# How to Converting web.config file to .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-config

Can anybody help me to convert this `web.config` file to `.htaccess`

```
<rules>    
      <rule name="Rewrite to index" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="^(.+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
            <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?permalink={R:1}" />
      </rule>
</rules>
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a standard front controller pattern. ie. Internally rewrite all requests to `index.php?permalink=<URL>` that don't map to an existing file or directory.

So, something like this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?permalink=$1 [L]
```